# Where do I put the braces in this multi block statement?

Tags: java, checkstyle

```
public static int countPopular(int count0, int count1, int count2) {
    int result;
    if (count0 > count1 && count0 > count2) {
        result = 0;

    }

    else if (count1 > count0 && count1 > count2) {
        result = 1;
    }

    else if (count2 > count0 && count2 > count1) {
        result = 2;
    }
    else {
        result = -1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Having issues figuring out where I am missing parenthesis in this multi-block statement.

```
Message: '}' at column 7 should be on the same line as the next part of a multi-block statement (one that directly contains multiple blocks: if/else-if/else, do/while or try/catch/finally).


Line: 28    Message: '}' at column 7 should be on the same line as the next part of a multi-block statement (one that directly contains multiple blocks: if/else-if/else, do/while or try/catch/finally).


Line: 32    Message: '}' at column 7 should be on the same line as the next part of a multi-block statement
```

These are the error messages I am receiving.

Comment: Please explain what error message or behaviour makes you think the parentheses are wrong.

Comment: It's asking for you to put the if else/else statement onto the same line as the closing bracket from the last statement.

Comment: Those aren't errors. It is Checkstyle telling you that your code doesn't comply with the conventions it should be following.

Comment: You should be aware that it's not a requirement of the language; it's just a style that some people (not me) like.

Answer (score 0):

Like This:

```
public static int countPopular(int count0, int count1, int count2) {
    int result;
    if (count0 > count1 && count0 > count2) {
        result = 0;
    }else if (count1 > count0 && count1 > count2) {
        result = 1;
    }else if (count2 > count0 && count2 > count1) {
        result = 2;
    }else {
        result = -1;
    }
    return result;
}
```